# How to use HTTP proxies in Python3?

Tags: http, python-3.x, proxy

I am trying to connect to websites using HTTP proxies. I have tried using the requests modules' way:

```
import requests

proxies = {'http': '1.0.0.1:808'}

    a = requests.get('https://www.google.com', proxies=proxies)
    print(a.text)
```

This is the example code in the requests module's documentation. The code will print out the source of Google completely ignoring anything in the dictionary. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have scoured the internet looking how to check and use a HTTP proxy in Python3 and have had no luck.

Everything I find is in Python 2.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only set a HTTP proxy, but you're making a HTTPS request.  If you set `https` in the dictionary similar to `http`, you should have your proxy working.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! The love of debugging. haha. Pays off to have attention to detail. Thank you very much!